# After the last written line, I want it to declare end of file instead of producing a new line

Tags: c, file, file-io, eof

So I am looking to edit this code, it produces a format in a text file of something like this:

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:123123123123
0000:0000:0000:0000:132151253251
```

I want to have it do a new line unless it is the last entry. If it is the last entry then it will declare an end of file:

Here is my code at the moment:

```
void save(int rCount, struct packet *records){
  FILE *recordFile;                 //file handle
  char fileName[30] = { '\0'};      //string to store the file name
  int i;

  puts("Enter a filename to save the records :");   //ask the user for the filename
  scanf("%s", fileName);                            //store the filename: data input should be checked
                                                    //here in your program

  //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
  if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL){
      printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
      exit(1);
  }
  else{ //the file opened so print the records array of Person's to it
      for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
          fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%d\n",records[i].source, records[i].destination, records[i].type, records[i].port, records[i].data);
      }
      fclose(recordFile);   //close the file
  }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be a better fit for Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you have a problem with the code now? If the code is working, and you want to refactor it, Code Review is the right place. If your code isn't behaving the way you want, reword your question to highlight that.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't moving the last entry out of the loop enough?

```
for(i=0; i < rCount - 1;i++){
      fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%d\n",records[i].source, records[i].destination, records[i].type, records[i].port, records[i].data);
  }
  fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%d",records[rCount - 1].source, records[rCount - 1].destination, records[rCount - 1].type, records[rCount - 1].port, records[v].data);
  fclose(recordFile);   //close the file
```

Answer (score 1):

change your for loop in this way:

```
  for(i=0; i<rCount; i++){
      if(i!=0) fprintf(recordFile,"\n");
      fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%d",records[i].source, records[i].destination, records[i].type, records[i].port, records[i].data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple hack:

```
  for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
      fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%d%s",records[i].source, records[i].destination, records[i].type, records[i].port, records[i].data,(i==(rCount-1))?"":"\n");
  }
```

Note, however, that it's considered a good practice to end a text file with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

EOF is not a printable character, so you can't really write a EOF at the end of the file. If you discard the last newline and close the file it should be enough. You should be able to use read that file until EOF.

Most commonly, but this is not a general  rule you write a null (\0) at the end of the file.

```
for(i=0; i < rCount - 1;i++){
  fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%d\n",records[i].source, records[i].destination, records[i].type, records[i].port, records[i].data);
 }
 fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%d\0",records[rCount - 1].source, records[rCount - 1].destination, records[rCount - 1].type, records[rCount - 1].port, records[v].data);
 fclose(recordFile);   //close the file
```

Comment: true, it's not mandatory it works both ways: with/without the null character -> I already mentioned this in my answer